# How to get elements that doesn't exist in a list in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to filter all objects from List A that don't exist in List B. How to do that in Dart?

```
List<MyModel> A = await _repository.myAPI();
List<MyModel> B = await _repository.myAPI();
List<FavoriteM> C = A.take(2).toList();
A.removeWhere((MyModel elem) => B.contains(elem)); // this Doesn't work
A.removeWhere((MyModel elem) => C.contains(elem)); // this works because List C are made from A;
```

The problem here is that the list A and B are different instances, even if they are both an instance of the same class, but still Dart see them as different.
My final goal is this:

```
List<MyModel> A = [obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4];
List<MyModel> B = [obj1, obj3];
A = [obj2, obj4]; // i want List A to have only the elements that doesn't exist in List B
```

How do i achieve that?

Comment: Did you mean `A.removeWhere(...)`?  It's not clear why that doesn't work.  List `A` and `B` of course are different instances (otherwise all objects from `A` that don't exist in `B` would be the empty list).  Do you mean that the *elements* are all unique instances?  If so, then override `MyModel.operator ==`.

Comment: @jamesdlin yes i meant `A.removeWhere(...)` i edited my question. how can i override `MyModel.operator ==` ?

Comment: See http://pchalin.blogspot.com/2014/04/defining-equality-and-hashcode-for-dart.html for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can definitely achieve using overriding == operator ad @jamesdlin suggests in his comment.

i would like to introduce [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package which overriding == operator for us ad well as we don't have to worry about hash code.

You have to just extends Equatable and pass all the variables to props as below code.

```
class Person extends Equatable {
  final String name;

  Person(this.name);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name];
}
```

now You can compare to objects, so your code will work.

**Note:** If you are using json then check equatable package carefully and change your code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this gets over the different instances issue that you are having but if the objects in the lists were strings then this is a simple solution using sets:

```
void main() {
  Set<String> A = {"obj1", "obj2", "obj3", "obj4"};
  Set<String> B = {"obj1", "obj3"};

  print(A.difference(B)); // prints {obj2, obj4}
}
```

You would need to convert your lists to sets and then back again...or use sets in the first place.

Can't test it further myself but hope it helps.